# Non-ASCII Environment variables set by Qt cannot be retrieved correctly in Python

Tags: python, qt, unicode, utf-8, environment-variables

Set a environment variable "GAME_FILENAME" using the following code in Qt where `args[0]` contains a file name `alättet.DTA` -

```
qputenv("GAME_FILENAME", qUtf8Printable(args[0])); //args[0]='\temp\alättet.DTA'
```

When the environment variable is retrieved in Python code with the following code, variable `files` is as shown here:

[image: files output in a message box]

One character `'ä'` became two. Looking into `fBytes`, there are 4 bytes corresponding to `'ä'`.

```
files = os.environ.get('GAME_FILENAME')

fBytes = bytes(os.environ.get('GAME_FILENAME'))
```

Verified on the Qt side by storing the result of `qgetenv('GAME_FILENAME')` in a `QByteArray`. The bytes look correct. Also in Python, tried `os.environ['GAME_FILENAME']="alättet.DTA"`, then `os.environ.get('GAMRY_FILENAME')` returns `"alättet.DTA"` correctly.

Anything missed here? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that Qt and Python are using different encodings.

Comment: A [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'alättet'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'alÃ¤ttet'`…

Comment: Please clarify if the first code snippet is C++ or Python.

Comment: qputenv("GAME_FILENAME", qUtf8Printable(args[0])); //This is C++/Qt code